# jquery tipsy tooltip not working with d3.js circles

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, d3.js, tipsy

Here is my d3.js code

```
var circles = vis.selectAll("circle").data(data)
circles
    .enter()
        .append("svg:circle")
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .attr("cx", function (d) { return xRange(d.year); })
            .attr("cy", function (d) { return yRange(d.count); })
            .style("fill", function(d,i){return color(i);})
        .append("svg:title")
            .text(function (d) { return d.corpus; })
```

In the end i have appended a tooltip to the circles.I tried to attach jquery tipsy tooltip to the circles but did'nt work.Here is how i did it(i followed `http://bl.ocks.org/1373263`)

```
var circles = vis.selectAll("circle").data(data)
circles
    .enter()
        .append("svg:circle")
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .attr("cx", function (d) { return xRange(d.year); })
            .attr("cy", function (d) { return yRange(d.count); })
            .style("fill", function(d,i){return color(i);})
        $('svg circle').tipsy({ 
                            gravity: 'w', 
                            html: true, 
                            title: function (d) {
                            return d.corpus;
                          }
                       });
```

But its not working.

Comment: What error messages (if any) are you getting? Do you have a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) we could look at?

Comment: no error message.I'm not able to c the tooltip

Comment: @socialrel8 here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RPGPL/3/   without the tooltip.Can u let me know how to add jquery tipsy tooltip to it

Comment: I just compared the code in this question to the sample you have pointed out. This is how it is done in the example :         $('svg circle').tipsy({ 
                            gravity: 'w', 
                            html: true, 
                            title: function () {
                            var d = this.__data__, c = colors(d.i);
                            return d.corpus;
                          }
                       });

Comment: @TJ- my mistake u r rite thnks,Issue solved

Comment: Cool. Glad it is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing this.**data**

```
$('svg circle').tipsy({ 
                            gravity: 'w', 
                            html: true, 
                            title: function (d) {
                               var d = this.__data__;
                               return d.corpus;
                          }
                       });
```