# Tooltip for D3.js graphs

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip

I want to make a tooltip for a realtime D3.js and javascript graph that moves smoothly on the data. Does any one know any example. All I have found is related to static graphs.

Comment: see here http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/adding-tooltips-to-d3js-graph.html

Comment: check this http://bl.ocks.org/1373263

Comment: this may also help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568802/jquery-tipsy-tooltip-not-working-with-d3-js-circles

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579

Answer (score 0):

If your data is bound to `<g>` elements, you can add the tooltips to the `<g>` as a `<text>` element. Or, you could use a `<foreignObject>` with some nested HTML if you'd prefer CSS styling.